# How can I determine what objects ARC is retaining using Instruments or viewing assembly?

Tags: performance, swift, assembly, instruments

This question is not about finding out who retained a particular object but rather looking at a section of code that appears from the profiler to have excessive retain/release calls and figuring out *which* objects are responsible.

I have a Swift application that after initial porting was spending 90% of its time in retain/release code.  After a great deal of restructuring to avoid referencing objects I have gotten that down to about 25% - but this remaining bit is very hard to attribute.  I can see that a given chunk of it is coming from a given section of code using the profiler, but sometimes I cannot see anything in that code that should (to my understanding) be causing a retain/release.  I have spent time viewing the assembly code in both Instruments (with the side-by-side view when it's working) and also the output of `otool -tvV` and sometimes the proximity of the retain/release calls to a recognizable section give me a hint as to what is going on. I have even inserted dummy method calls at places just to give me a better handle on where I am in the code and turned off optimization to limit code reordering, etc.  But in many cases it seems like I would have to trace the code back to follow branches and figure out what is on the stack in order to understand the calls and I am not familiar enough with x86 to know know if that is practical.  (I will add a couple of screenshots of the assembly view in Instruments and some otool output for reference below).

My question is - what else can I be doing to debug / examine / attribute these seemingly excessive retain/release calls to particular code?  Is there something else I can do in Instruments to count these calls?  I have played around with the allocation view and turned on the reference counting option but it didn't seem to give me any new information (I'm not actually sure what it did).  Alternately, if I just try harder to interpret the assembly should I be able to figure out what objects are being retained by it?  Are there any other tools or tricks I should know on that front?

[image: Instruments assembly view]
[image: otool assembly view]

EDIT: Rob's info below about single stepping into the assembly was what I was looking for.  I also found it useful to set a symbolic breakpoint in XCode on the lib retain/release calls and log the item on the stack (using Rob's suggested "p (id)$rdi") to the console in order to get a rough count of how many calls are being made rather than inspect each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely focus on the assembly output. There are two views I find most useful: the Instruments view, and the Assembly assistant editor. The problem is that Swift doesn't support the Assembly assistant editor currently (I typically do this kind of thing in ObjC), so we come around to your complaint.

It looks like you're already working with the debug assembly view, which gives somewhat decent symbols and is useful because you can step through the code and hopefully see how it maps to the assembly. I also find [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com) useful, because it can give more symbols. Once you have enough "unique-ish" function calls in an area, you can usually start narrowing down how the assembly maps back to the source.

The other tool I use is to step into the retain bridge and see what object is being passed. To do this, instruction-step (^F7) into the call to `swift_bridgeObjectRetain`. At that point, you can call:

```
p (id)$rdi
```

And it should print out at least some type information about the what's being passed (`$rdi` is correct on x86_64 which is what you seem to be working with). I don't always have great luck extracting more information. It depends on exactly is in there. For example, sometimes it's a `ContiguousArrayStorage<Swift.CVarArgType>`, and I happen to have learned that usually means it's an `NSArray`. I'm sure better experts in LLDB could dig deeper, but this usually gets me at least in the right ballpark.

(BTW, I don't know why I can't call `p (id)$rdi` *before* jumping inside `bridgeObjectRetain`, but it gives strange type errors for me. I have to go into the function call.)

Wish I had more. The Swift tool chain just hasn't caught up to where the ObjC tool chain is for tracing this kind of stuff IMO.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know about instruction-stepping in the debugger and this gives me some hope of figuring out what is being retained.  I take it  `p (id)$rdi` it's printing the contents of the $rdi register cast as an object id?  Do you know that this is the argument just from calling conventions or should I see it in the assembly?  Also, when instruction-stepping it seems that XCode often doesn't actually show me any assembly until I hit certain functions.  It sits on a line of source code as I repeatedly hit ^F7.  Is this normal?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, `(id)` just means "pretend it's an object". `$rdi` comes from x86_64 calling conventions; the debugger doesn't help you know that (and it's different for ARM of course). And yes, ^F7 doesn't always dive in quite the way you'd want it to. I sometimes have to experiment to see what combination of steps will get me what I wanted. And of course if you can work on unoptimized code (Debug mode), that's much better. The assembly is going to map to the source much better. (Some performance issues are radically different in Debug/Release of course, but when you can get away with Debug....)